# How to do 'hard page reload' in Chrome browser on mobile android smartphone

Tags: android, google-chrome, caching, reload

Problem: I was trying to see if a web page of my product looks well on mobile, and got a cached version of it. looking elsewhere on stackoverflow, i found the answer, but it was buried inside another question that was less accurate to this issue, so decide to ask-and-answer here as well.

Just to be clear, what i was trying to do was:

- ensure i'm not getting a cached version of this page ONLY, while
- NOT clearing cache for any other page in my Chrome for Android (i believe it will be the same for iPhone, but did not test it yet)

Answer (score 2):

Answer is based on [yPhil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729094/yphil) answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571213/how-can-i-force-a-hard-reload-in-chrome-for-android).

1. Click on the Chrome menu, while on the page you want 'hard reloading'

[image: chrome menu]

2. Click on the 'info' icon

[image: info]

3. Click on 'Site Settings'

[image: site setting]

4. Either click on the 'delete' icon (option 1) or the 'Clear & Reset' button (option 2). See question and answer on the difference between the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969315/whats-the-difference-between-normal-reload-hard-reload-and-empty-cache-a), where 'delete' is doing 'hard reload' and 'clear & reset' doing 'empty cache and hard reload' on the accepted answer by Andrew Rasmussen.

[image: site settings dialog]

I chose 'Clear & Reset' for my needs, but choose whatever suits yours.

Clear & Reset Dialog:

[image: clear and reset dialog]

Delete Dialog:

[image]

Comment: Sadly, google removes this option, and change all interface

Comment: Looks like the current mobile Chrome UI has changed slightly for this procedure. Now, after you tap the Info (i) icon, you'd tap Cookies and Site Data, then tap the trashcan icon to delete cookies/cache data for the current page.

Clearing the browser's entire cache and cookies would now be done via the main Chrome menu > Clear browsing data.

Answer (score 2):

Android Chrome is really annoying, I've noticed this in last months.
I use workaround by adding querystring to js static resources like **?foo=1**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/a.js?foo=1"></script>
```

Nasty, but functional.