# Is there any way to use JavaScript to do a Ctrl-F5?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way that I can do a CTRL-F5 type of refresh and reload the whole browser window? I've tried the following code:

```
function showRefresh()
{
    window.location.reload(true); 
}
```

The page doesn't seem to want to refresh correctly. If I do a CTRL-F5 on my keyboard it reloads fine. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it is duplicate.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5721805/2476755) on the linked question provides the solution you're after

Answer (score -2):

You could do this as well:

```
function showRefresh(){
    window.location = window.location;
}
```