# How to add link to restart button in html5 game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

I tried using this but did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#restartBtn").click(function(){
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

This is my code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1125" height="2436" class="" style="width: 375px; height: 812px;"></canvas>

<img id="restartBtn" src="./images/btn_restart.svg" style="display: inline;">
```

Can we add link on that restart button?

Comment: Your code should work fine. What doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe a cache problem?

Comment: try typing in browser console: `location.reload()`, if it can refresh the page, then it should be working, and probably just a cache problem

Comment: Have you tried using `location.reload(true);`? This question might be helpful and it has the suggestion given has been accpeted as a working solution/answer [**window.location.reload with clear cache**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721704/window-location-reload-with-clear-cache#answer-5722855)