# How to control if PWA uses cached version or fetches latest version?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have installed my PWA from Chrome and Firefox on Android, and from Safari on iOS. When I update my code on the website, I see quite different behaviour in the PWAs in terms of using older cached versions vs the newest one - Firefox-created PWA seems to require about 2-3 kill and restarts of the PWA, Chrome takes 5-6, and I couldn't get Safari-based PWA to start showing the newest version without deleting the PWA and re-adding to Home Screen from browser.

Is there a spec that defines the conditions under which a newer, non-cached version is fetched? After much reading, I disabled the registering of my service worker, which should have made the PWAs network-only (no service-worker cache) but I continue to get old versions of the site served up in the PWAs. A normal browser window also seems to require multiple deep refreshes to get the new version, so I assume there is something besides the service worker that determines this?

Comment: I think the issue more of a how you serve your PWA ,is it a cache first,if yes then it will respond to request from cached files instead of fetching it from network

Comment: Could you give more detail on what you mean by this please?

Comment: where are you maintaining the version ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.I will break it in parts:

```
   self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(


    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        return fetch(event.request).then(
          function(response) {
            // Check if we received a valid response
            if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
              return response;
            }

            // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
            // and because we want the browser to consume the response
            // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
            // to clone it so we have two streams.
            var responseToCache = response.clone();

            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
              });

            return response;
          }
        );
      })
    );
});
```

Over here cached first strategy is used,whenever you reload the page a fetch event is triggered.

```
caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
```

First it checks if the required request is available in the cache,if yes then it will return the response and won't fetch from network.

```
 return fetch(event.request).then(
          function(response) {
            // Check if we received a valid response
            if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
              return response;
            }

            // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
            // and because we want the browser to consume the response
            // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
            // to clone it so we have two streams.
            var responseToCache = response.clone();

            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
              });

            return response;
          }
        );
      })
    );
```

Now if the file was not present in the cache then this block gets to network gathers the required files then respond with it an also save it to cache for further use.

Consider the case that you have a file sample.html and it is cached,now you make some changes to the file's code but the changes won't be seen on your browser because it will see that the sample.html(old) was already present in the cache and respond with it.

Comment: Thanks, but if I've not registered a Service Worker (as stated) then it should always do a network fetch, not cached?

Comment: you could probably use window.loaction.reload(true) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721704/window-location-reload-with-clear-cache

I would suggest you to use service worker as they are meant for PWA

Answer (score -1):

Few generalized considerations regarding SW and PWAs:
Once you register your Service Worker (SW), you have to un-register it to make it sure you get the latest/updated version, and you can do so in the application tab under service worker 
[image: SW un-register]

and then

[image: Cache storage clear]

to make sure you get the latest/update version of you PWA. What else you can do on top of it is, you can change the object name of the cache storage like below:
[image: Changing the object name].

As long as you keep the object name same as well as don't unregister the SW and clear the Cache storage either, you will have to refresh your website. There is also, **hard reload/clear cache and hard reload** option as well if you keep pressing the refreshing button of the browser for couple of seconds but it still doesn't work until you unregister your service worker. So, in short unregistering SW and clearing Cache storage manually or changing the name of the Cache storage object will do the trick. Like any other technology/asset there are pros and cons. This is one of the draw back of the PWA if we don't use it properly, your client will never get the latest version, or the time he will get it may be too late. Cheers:)

Comment: if you are providing the solution so at least give a proper solution for the same