# php files downloaded instead of parsing, issue resolved from server, old users keep downloading even now

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, browser

Explanation : some php handler issue occurred at server-side, which made all of my php file getting downloaded from server on 8-10 of my domains (hosted on same hosting) instead of parsing and displaying.

Server people claim that they have corrected, if i visit the sites now from my regular PC & browser the url is still giving me files to download. if from anyother PC or Browser its parsing the page and not downloading.

It 99% seems cached content issue after their efforts.

Problem : All of my OLD-regular users are now getting the files download rather parse. I cannot contact every user to clear their browser cache (if it is cache issue).

What can i do to resolve issue as a webmaster and make all my users get files parsed rather download.

Comment: If their clients don’t make a new request to your server to check if the content was updated, then there is little you can do.

Comment: @CBroe Can javascript solutions like (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721704/window-location-reload-with-clear-cache) OR (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099201/javascript-hard-refresh-of-current-page) help?? if yes, how can i implement as even index file is directly downloading rather than parsing. on 1 of my site service worker is available and installed in that case anything? for all rest of sites there doesnt seems to be a  solution.

Comment: You can’t fix anything using new code now, if you can’t get those clients to _request_ your new code to begin with. So if the index page is already cached, then you can’t make that load any _new_ resources now. And a webworker is probably also not going to take care of this suddenly now without any changes to its own code, if it did not have any cache / refresh functionality built-in already.