# How to get all browsers to ignore cache for web applications

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I don't want my browsers to cache anything. The issue is javascript and html keeps getting cached by IE9 and other browsers we use. Whilest we can do ctrl F5, external users can't be trusted to remeber to do this.

How can I setup my MVC web appplication to ignore caches

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954189/how-to-disable-internet-explorer-cache-using-javascript-or-php

Comment: `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When loading your resources, I would append a timestamp or something random to your requests, so they will be unique and not be cached by the browser.

You can also refer to: [Disable browser cache for entire ASP.NET website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/disable-browser-cache-for-entire-asp-net-website) for more on how to send no-cache headers from ASP.NET. Note, put those settings in the *Global.asax.cs*-file.