# refresh webpage programmatically - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript hard refresh of current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099201/javascript-hard-refresh-of-current-page)

Is there a way to refresh a page using javascript? I'm using jQuery Mobile to display some statistics in a listview (probably a listview), and I need to re-populate the data from a MySQL db every 10 seconds, let's say. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Depending on your setup, you can use AJAX to do so, or just simply refresh the page with JavaScript.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  In probably several different ways.  Which way have you tried.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is about JQM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using JQM use the listview.('refresh') method on a list view. Use ajax and call .refresh() on the list in the handler.

```
$.ajax({ /* code goes here */ 
 success : function(e) { for (var i in e.data) 
 { listView.add(i); } 
   listview.listview('refresh'); });
```

FROM JQM Docs: 
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html
Updating lists
If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added. For example:

$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
Note that the refresh() method only affects new nodes appended to a list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated, replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

Comment: could you provide some sample to put this on a recurring basis every 10 seconds? I know the code's simple but I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok but again, how would I put the listview method .refresh() on a recurring basis? Thanks a lot

Comment: it refreshes everytime the ajax call completes

Comment: If you want to do it on a recurring basis use a setTimeout() function and call listview.listview('refresh').

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using ajax for this. But to refresh a page in JS, just do:

`window.location.reload();`

or

`window.location.href = window.location.href;`

Comment: The first works for me in IE and Chrome (didn't test it on others), but the second method didn't work in either browser?

Comment: I confirm that `window.location.reload()` works in Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome for the simple case of refreshing the whole page.