# Update one page with jQuery, in single html file

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've got a single html with 5 pages + navbar. To force a refresh of one page I use this:

```
$("#page3").on("pagecreate", function(e) {});
```

It works the first time, but I want it to update every time I visit the page. I know there is .trigger("create"), and "refresh", but I can't get it to work properly...

jQuery Mobile 1.4.0

Comment: `pagecreate` fires once per _page_. `.trigger("create")` is deprecated and replaced with `.enhanceWithin()`. What do you want to refresh exactly?

Comment: I want #page3 to reload everytime i browse to it. It holds some data I need to be updated. Or placing it inside a <div and only updating that specific <div could also work...

Comment: I think you want a hard refresh. Your question has been answered here, and can be achieved without jQuery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099201/javascript-hard-refresh-of-current-page

Comment: @AKG this jQM not jQuery, `window.reload()` will reload the whole document. in jQM _page_ is a div inside a document.

Comment: Then you need to use `pagecontainerbeforeshow` to update page's content. Are you retrieving data via Ajax?

Comment: On this page there is no Ajax. It holds a "summary" of some data based on the other pages, so it's generated only on the client.

Comment: Then all you need is on `pagecontainerbeforeshow` collect data from other pages and update _that_ page. Or, create page dynamically and remove it once you navigate away.

Comment: Doesn't work.. The event is not triggered. $("#page3").on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(e) { alert("test"); });

Comment: Good that you've tried it ;) Unfortunately, new _pageContainer_ events cant be attached to a specific page. You need to check which page is currently visible, if this == "page3" doSomething().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48938/discussion-between-omar-and-baked-inhalf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to listen to `pageContainer` event in order to determine which page is active and accordingly run the functions you want.

The new events can't be attached to a specific page, unlike successor versions of jQuery Mobile. Once an event is occurred, retrieve `ActivePage`'s ID.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function (e, ui) {
  var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id;
  if(activePage == "page3") {
    doSomething();
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UvP9F/)**