# Clear cache browser while loading website at any time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the website goes live from local we have to press **F5** to reload the web page. Can we give idea to clear cache while loading website? Is there any jQuery or JavaScript for hard refreshing a website?

Comment: press shift+F5 together.

Comment: Thanks but Without shift + F5 , can we automatic hard refresh using javascirp or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the cache-control and the expires META Tag.

> 

Another common practices is to append constantly-changing strings to the end of the requested files. For instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js?v=12392823"></script>
```

[Another Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
location.reload(true);
```

This will reload the page from the server.
Do your research!
([Javascript hard refresh of current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099201/javascript-hard-refresh-of-current-page)).