# Force page refresh without meta tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am tired of telling clients to refresh their web page to see a new change I have made. I have tried meta tags like below but not 100% working

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
```

Does anyone know of a simple javascript or jquery i can use to force browser to display the latest version of the page

Comment: Why bother to search when you can have us do it for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript hard refresh of current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099201/javascript-hard-refresh-of-current-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a page using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: I have searched this for hours - most examples have a button for the user to click or other examples dont work. Could i pls have example code of using window.location.reload();

Answer (score 0):

To force the browser get the las changes of the html files, you can use a timestamp in the uri of the files. For example the src of the link:

> 'index.html?' + Date.now()

(depends on the language)

In the link of the html you should see href='index.html?1508171457516' , and the query param don't affect to the behaviour of the html.

Comment: ? seems very messy

Comment: not really messy, this is used all the time to keep content fresh. Date.now() just returns ticks so it's a number.

Answer (score -2):

You can try adding this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20" />
```

to your headers to force the browser to refresh every 20 seconds (or whatever other interval you want to use).

Edited: For those who believe that this won't work (ref. comments) - try this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5'>
<title>Clock Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo "<h1>Clock</h1>";
    $latest = date("H:i:s");
    echo "<p>The time is ".$latest."</p>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Title says: Force page refresh without meta tags, thats a meta

Comment: Silly me - never read the title properly just looked at the content. I guess the answer then becomes window.location.reload(false);  but this has already been dealt with in other posts as mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript

Comment: It does work, we use it every day for an auto refresh program. Just make sure that you put it at the top of your meta tags.