# Force Hard Reload

Tags: javascript, html, reload

I am currently attempting to create a simple test to test the speed of the client's PC by rendering an image. The issue is on browsers such as Safari and Chrome images a saved in some way to allow for a quick reload speed. For example when using the following code

```
var speed = document.getElementById('speed');
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var stopTime = new Date().getTime();
    var loadtime = Math.round((stopTime - startTime) / 100);
}
img.src = "testImage.jpg";
```

The variable `loadtime` is `8` at first and then `0` after a refresh. My guess is Safari saves the image to load it instantly. On Chrome it's the same issue unless I do a hard reload. I've tried putting these `meta` tags but with no luck.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

I've also tried

```
location.reload(true);
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099201/javascript-hard-refresh-of-current-page) but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Is it possible to force a hard reload without the client's consent or chose? Or is it some sort of security infringement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting meta tags and reloading the HTML page does not affect the caching of the image. If you want to avoid caching the image try appending a random query parameter each time for example.

```
img.src = "testImage.jpg?q=" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a harmless query parameter to the end of the url to break the browser's caching:

```
img.src="testImage.jpg?noop=<incrementing_number_here>"
```