# How to clear cache by command in ionic web app?

Tags: ionic-framework, caching, web-applications, ionic3, browser-cache

When I upload the latest version of my web application to the server, the user must do the following to see the latest version:

1. If the program is running in the browser it should hit the shift + f5 buttons.
2. If the program is running in the mobile browser, it should clear the cache as follows:

Settings / Privacy / Clear browsing data / Clear data

[image]

Now how can we do this automatically with programming so that the user doesn't have to?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099205/5909026

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Where can i use this? (i'm in ionic)

Comment: You can add it in your `index.html` // i haven't tested it but i assume it will work.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I'm add <script>location.reload(true);</script> to index.php but dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added version (ex: `?ver=1.0`) to the end of scripts in the index.html file:

```
<!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js?ver=2.2"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js?ver=2.2"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js?ver=2.2"></script>
```

And then increase the version number each time you upload it

Answer (score 0):

to store data you need sqlite or native storage blugin

- with sqlite you can use simple delete requet
- with blugin you can set your data to null or use delete methode