# reload page using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to reload a page using Javascript in my php code.

The page must be a fresh copy from the server.

I've tried the following:

1) Inserting a reload code in the code

```
echo "<script>
location.reload(true);
</script>";
```

**Problem:** this code keeps reloading the page.

2) Going back in the parent page:

```
echo "<script>window.location.href = document.referrer;</script>";
or
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

**Problem:** this code does not get a fresh copy from the server, resulting in a outdated page.

Is there a way that i can reload (getting a fresh copy from the server) that runs only once, or get a parent, but updated page?

What am i missing here?

Comment: Try adding a condition around the reload. When do you want the page to reload? Maybe in response to some event or application state? If you have no condition, that's an infinite loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript hard refresh of current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099201/javascript-hard-refresh-of-current-page)

Comment: @ggorlen (second comment), nope, because the reload(true) causes a infinite loop.

Comment: @ggorlen how can i loose the infinite loop? The condition is just to reload once.

Comment: Multiple ways to do it, although this practice seems pretty atypical. You could set a flag in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), set a cookie or make a remote request to a server database. It's a design call that's up to you.