# javascript how to force hard refresh of current page

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a button in a webapp that when clicked on should **hard**-reload the page and all its components.
I make changes to one of the javascript files (file1.js) but the changes are not updated.

According to:
[here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/location-reload-method-how-to-reload-a-page-in-javascript/) and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099201/javascript-hard-refresh-of-current-page) using `window.location.reload(true);`
should reload the page from the server.
In my program, clicking on the button triggers this line of code, but the changes still not show up.
The code is bundled via webpack.

When clicking on the button, the *Network* tab in *Chrome debugger* shows the network requests that are associated with reloading the page.
One of them is the main page.

- It's Request Headers shows `cache-control: no-cache`
- It's Response Headers shows `Cache-Control`

Further down in the list, I see `app.bundle.js` which includes the specific file *file1.js*.
The *General* section for `app.bundle.js` shows `Status Code: 200  (from memory cache)`

So clearly, not all elements of the page are reloaded from the server.
Below are the sections from the Chrome debugger Network tab.
**How can I force loading all the pages not from cache?**

Sections from *Network* tab in *Chrome debugger*

```
# Network request fields for getting https://staging.bldlog.com/index

General:
   Request URL: https://staging.bldlog.com/index
   Request Method: GET
   Status Code: 200 
   ...

Request Headers:
   :authority: staging.bldlog.com
   :method: GET
   :path: /index
...
   cache-control: no-cache


Response Headers:
   access-control-allow-headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range


# --------------------------------------------------------------

# Network request fields for getting https://staging.bldlog.com/V1/build/mlj/app.bundle.js

General:
   Request URL: https://staging.bldlog.com/V1/build/mlj/app.bundle.js
   Request Method: GET
   Status Code: 200  (from memory cache)
```

Comment: http://cristian.sulea.net/blog/disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It helped me to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to specify
`{ 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' };` in the request header as instructed in [here](http://cristian.sulea.net/blog/disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags/)

Comment: Do you mean the response header?

Comment: I placed it in the request header, in the javascript code.
This causes the browser to not return a cached response but to redirect to the backend.